# UWP control to keep focus after mouse click

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a canvas (technically a SkiaSharp `SKXamlCanvas`) that I need to host in a control that can get focus (for reasons I won't go into here). I added the canvas as a child to a class (call it `ControlHost`) derived from `ContentControl` and set the canvas as the `Content`. The `ControlHost's` `GetFocus` gets called when I open the app, but when I click on the `ControlHost` (which takes up the whole window), I get a `LostFocus` after releasing the mouse button.

I know things like `TextBox` keep focus after clicking on them with the mouse. Is there another control I can use that will keep focus and simply act as a container for my canvas? I've tried `UserControl`, `Frame`, `Page`, etc. Or maybe there are properties I can set on a `ContentControl` that will allow it to keep focus?

This can easily be reproduced by making a blank UWP app and adding the following control as a child to the grid of `MainPage`.

```
public class ContentControlTest : ContentControl
{
    public ContentControlTest()
    {
        GotFocus += OnGotFocus;
        LostFocus += OnLostFocus;
    }

    private void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnLostFocus");
    }

    private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnGotFocus");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> UWP control to keep focus after mouse click

It is by-desgin that  `ContentControl` will lost focus when `PointerReleased`.  The ContentControl inherit from `Control`. so it has `Focus` method, if you want to keep focus, you could try to call Focus method in `OnLostFocus` like following.

```
private void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("OnLostFocus");
    this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

Comment: If I were to have another control on the page, this would inhibit that control from ever taking focus. Is there no control that I can use as a container that keeps focus?

Comment: Yep, it always keep focus, and it's by design.

Comment: So if I want to not do that, and I want to allow other controls to gain focus, but don't want to lose focus on mouse-up, is there no alternative? I could derive from TextBox, but I'd have to figure out how to remove all the visual styling to make it a simple container for other controls.

Comment: You could get the default TextBox Style [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/CommonStyles/TextBox_themeresources.xaml#L79). you could custom the style and hide the content.

Comment: Ok. So there is nothing (no properties being applied to TextBox) that I could apply to a UserControl or ContentControl to make those be able to behave like TextBox and keep focus after clicking on them?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can keep focus after clicking on a ContentControl.

By default, after the ContentControl's PointerReleased event is triggered, the ContentControl's LostFocus event is triggered (a control loses focus when another one gets it).

Thus, you can modify the default behavior by adding a custom PointerReleased event handler to the ContentControl. Since PointerReleased is a routed event, you simply need to add `e.Handled = true`.

```
private void ControlHost_PointerReleased(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent most handlers along the event route from handling the same event again.
    e.Handled = true;
}
```